# Unbuffered channels

Tags: go

I'm doing the Go Tour: http://tour.golang.org/#72
This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree"
    "fmt"
)

// Walk walks the tree t sending all values
// from the tree to the channel ch.
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    var makeWalk func(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int)

    makeWalk = func(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
        if t.Left != nil {
            makeWalk(t.Left, ch)

        }
        fmt.Println("-->", t.Value)
        ch <- t.Value
        fmt.Println("continue here")
        if t.Right != nil {
            makeWalk(t.Right, ch)
        }
    }
    makeWalk(t, ch)
    close(ch)
}

// Same determines whether the trees
// t1 and t2 contain the same values.
func Same(t1, t2 *tree.Tree) bool {
 //   var ch_l chan int = make(chan int)
 // var ch_r chan int = make(chan int)
    return false
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)    
    for i := range(ch) {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
--> 1
continue here
--> 2
1
2
continue here
--> 3
continue here
--> 4
3
4
continue here
--> 5
continue here
--> 6
5
6
continue here
--> 7
continue here
--> 8
7
8
continue here
--> 9
continue here
--> 10
9
10
continue here
```

As far as I understand channels block when they are passed with values. I expect to see an output like this:

```
--> 1
1
continue here
--> 2
2
continue here
...
--> 10
10
continue here
```

Channels are not buffered, is `fmt.Println` buffered? What happens here? :)

Comment: there is no sync mechanism, so the main function receives from the channel, now the goroutine can send on the channel and advances, but this happens sometimes before the Println is called. So you get this "random" behavior.

Comment: If I understand you - channels are blocking correctly, but send/receive is faster than the `Println` in `main`? By the way what is the correct way to sync this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track when you mention `fmt.Println`.  Channel reads and writes are not the only time the scheduler can switch to another goroutine.  A blocking system call can also trigger a context switch.

From the [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#goroutines):

> When a coroutine blocks, such as by calling a blocking system call,
>   the run-time automatically moves other coroutines on the same
>   operating system thread to a different, runnable thread so they won't
>   be blocked.

`fmt.Println` will ultimately call a blocking system call (`write()`), so that's why you're seeing this behavior.